# Why useEffect runs multiple times in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I'm developing a Time Tracking component in Next.js application. Here's my TimeTracking (./app/components/TimeTracking.tsx) component:

```
'use client';

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

const TimeTracking = () => {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('session ===> ', session);
    let initialTimeStampSetUp: boolean = false;
    console.log('initialTimeStampSetUp ===> ', initialTimeStampSetUp);
    if (!initialTimeStampSetUp) {
      const initialTimeStamp: Date = new Date();
      console.log('initialTimeStamp ===> ', initialTimeStamp);
      initialTimeStampSetUp = true;
      console.log('initialTimeStampSetUp ===> ', initialTimeStampSetUp);
    }

    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && session) {
      const handleBeforeUnload = () => {
        const requestBody = JSON.stringify({
          initialTimeStamp: initialTimeStamp,
          date: new Date(),
        });

        navigator.sendBeacon(`/api/user/${session?.user?._id}`, requestBody);
      };

      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);

      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
      };
    }
  }, [session]);

  return (
    <>
      <p>Time Tracking</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default TimeTracking;
```

Here's the layout.tsx where I have TimeTracking imported.

```
import '../scss/style.scss';
import './globals.css';
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
import Provider from '@/app/components/Provider';
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import type { Metadata } from 'next';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });
import TimeTracking from '@/app/components/TimeTracking';

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'LangAI app',
  description: 'Adaptive language learning app',
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/icon.png"></link>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#fff" />
      </head>
      <body className={inter.className} suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
        <div className="min-h-screen">
          <Provider>
            {children}
            <TimeTracking />
          </Provider>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I attached a screenshot of what it prints to the console. Why does it run useEffect multiple times? I'm using Next.js version 13.4.16

[image]

Comment: Are you using the recent app router or the pages router?

Comment: Is this also the case in release mode? (`npm run build && npm run start`)

Comment: @AmirHosseinBaghernezad app router

Comment: @SamyRahmani it's in development mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that its rendering multiple times (at least twice) is becuase [React's Strict Mode is enabled by default.](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode)

Strict Mode enables the following development-only behaviors:

- Your components will re-render an extra time to find bugs caused by impure rendering.
- Your components will re-run Effects an extra time to find bugs caused by missing Effect cleanup.
- Your components will be checked for usage of deprecated APIs.

So you have 3 options.

#### Option 1:

Disable strict mode altogether. To do that in Next.js you can open the `next.config.js` file and add the `reactStrictMode: false` line to it.

```js
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
}
```

#### Option 2:

Use a `useRef` alongside every `useEffect` that you have created. Effectively preventing the code inside the hook from running more than once.

Take this as an example ([source](https://taig.medium.com/prevent-react-from-triggering-useeffect-twice-307a475714d7)):

```
const initialized = useRef(false)

useEffect(() => {
  if (!initialized.current) {
    initialized.current = true

    postIntegrationsTwitterLogin(oauth.token).then((session) => {
      setSession(session)
      router.replace("/dashboard")
    })
  }
}, [])
```

This will create the `initialized` variable and set it to `false`. When the hook is ran for the first time, `initialized` is set to `true` so from that moment onward, the code inside the hook will not run at all.

#### Option 3:

Use the application in production mode (I mean building it using `next build`). But in this way you have to build the entire app for a single change every time. Which does not seem to be a good approach.

Comment: so it was actually related to this line `import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';`. For some reason, by default `next-auth` will re-render the page every time the window gets back on focus